# Calculate percentage

Tags: reporting, servicecloud

I'm currently working on a report and am trying to calculate the proportion of record types. I have grouped the report by the RecordType but can't seem to find how to calculate the percentage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Report]

Answer (score 1):

This [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333690&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1) will probably work

**Create a custom summary formula**

1. Under Summary Formulas in the "Fields" pane, double-click Create Formula.
2. Enter a Column Name for the formula.  This will be the column header as you want it to appear on your report.
3. In the Description field, enter a brief description about the formula.
4. From the Formula Output Type picklist, select Percent.
5. Under Decimal Places, select the number of decimal places to be displayed.
6. Select the Display tab where the calculated formula should be displayed – select Specific Groups and then the desired grouping field (Row Group) to calculate percentage according to rows.
7. Build your formula:

To display the percentage of fields by grouping at a summary level, select the RowCount to consider total number of rows in each grouping and use the formula structure PARENTGROUPVAL(summary_field, grouping_level)
Complete Formula:  RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)
You can't plot summary formula(in a Y-axis) If in the source report the formula applied at a row group's grand total.